# What is the value of $SA\cdot S'A$ for the hyperbola ${ x }^{ 2 }-2{ y }^{ 2 }=1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

$S,S'$ are the foci and $A$ is the vertex. I have found the eccentricity $e$ to be $\sqrt { \frac { 3 }{ 2 }  } $ . I have also found out $S\equiv (\sqrt { \frac { 3 }{ 2 }  } ,0)$, $S'\equiv (-\sqrt { \frac { 3 }{ 2 }  } ,0)$ and $A\equiv (1,0)$. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  \frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2} &= 1 \\
  e &= \frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{a} \\
  SA \times S'A &= (ae-a)(ae+a) \\
  &= a^2(e^2-1) \\
  &= b^2 \\
  &= \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

For more information on product properties of confocal conics, see another answer [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1896801/ellipse-and-hyperbola-have-the-same-foci/1897836#1897836).

Comment: $SA . S'A = (ae-a)(ae+a)$ How did you get this ? How is $SA = ae -a$ ?

Comment: For standard form, vertices are $A(a,0)$, $A'(-a,0)$ and foci are $S(ae,0)$, $S'(-ae,0)$.  Therefore, $SA=(ae-a,0)$ and $S'A=(ae+a,0)$.