# Orthogonal tragectories

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the orthogonal trajectories of ellipses.
I have tried it but couldn't get .
My doubt is: in place of y' we write -1/y' but v also have y'' right what should be there in its place

Comment: Hint: see elliptic coordinates in another answer [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1896801/ellipse-and-hyperbola-have-the-same-foci/1897836#1897836)

Comment: You don't have to reduce the equation of your ellipse till second derivative,  just use it till first derivative,  and then replace y'with -1/y'  and use your given equation to find the orthogonal trajectory.

Comment: I still didn't get it can u pls solve it @Doraemon

Comment: I can show you Orthogonal Trajectory of Ellipse in which semi major and minor axis are dependent. For example,  a^2= c^2 ,b^2=c^2-1:As in this case you don't have to go for y".

Comment: @Doraemon thanks a lot