# What are explicit forms of $F(x,y)$ and $G(x,y)$ if $F(x,y)+iG(x,y)=\arcsin(x+iy)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-geometry

This relates to an earlier question and it answers in MSE:

[$\frac{x^2}{a^2+ \lambda}+ \frac{y^2}{b^2+\lambda}=1$ family with $-a^2< \lambda < -b^2$ orthogonal to family with $\lambda > -b^2>-a^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3482702/fracx2a2-lambda-fracy2b2-lambda-1-family-with-a2-lambda/3483068?noredirect=1#comment7161267_3483068)

In this regard, I have been trying to find explicit forms of $F(x,y)$ and $G(x,y)$ such that $$F(x,y)+iG(x,y)= \arcsin(x+iy)$$, they ought to be orthogonal but  I wonder if they confocal pairs of elipse and hyperbola or they are deceptively so. Any comment or  help is most welcome. I plot here $F(x,y)=\pm 1, G(x,y)=\pm 1$ for a visual aid.

[image]

Comment: Actually, either one of $w=\sinh^{-1} z$, $w=\cosh^{-1} z$, $w=\sin^{-1} z$ or $w=\cos^{-1} z$ will do.  They're all just up to switching the roles of real and imaginary parts or so for major and minor axes.

Comment: @Ng Chung, yes you are right.