# Spheroidal coordinates parametrisation

Tags: coordinate-systems, parametrization, ellipsoids

I am interested in working on spheroidal objects, and thus need to use spheroidal coordinates (in my case, prolate spheroidal coordinates). However, when doing some bibliography on the subject, I encountered two different ways of defining these coordinates.

The first one is the one found on the  [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolate_spheroidal_coordinates). The prolate spheroidal coordinates $(\nu, \mu, \varphi)$ is defined from the Cartesian coordinates $(x,y,z)$ such that
\begin{align}
x &= a \sinh(\mu) \sin(\nu) \cos (\varphi), \\
y &= a \sinh(\mu) \sin(\nu) \sin (\varphi), \\
z &= a \cosh(\mu) \cos(\nu),
\end{align}
where $a$ is a real constant. In particular, they obey the relation
$$
\frac{z^2}{a^2 \cosh^2 \mu} + \frac{x^2+y^2}{a^2 \sinh^2 \mu}=1,
$$
and
$$
\frac{z^2}{a^2 \cos^2 \nu} - \frac{x^2+y^2}{a^2 \sin^2 \nu}=1.
$$

The alternative one is the direct limit of the general case of the [ellipsoidal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoidal_coordinates). Here, the spheroidal coordinates $(\lambda, \phi, \nu)$ are defined from the cylindrical coordinates $(R=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, \phi, z)$ as the roots in $\tau$ of the equation (see, e.g, equation 2.1 of [this paper](https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/1988ApJ...333...90D) or equation 12 of [this one](https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/1985MNRAS.216..273D))
$$
\frac{R^2}{\tau+\alpha}+\frac{z^2}{\tau+\gamma}=\frac{x^2+y^2}{\tau+\alpha}+\frac{z^2}{\tau+\gamma}=1,
$$
where $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are real constants.

Are the two parametrisations equivalent ? If so, then what is the link between them?

Comment: Spheroidal coordinates are surface of revolution of (confocal) elliptic coordinates, please see my older post [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3482702/fracx2a2-lambda-fracy2b2-lambda-1-family-with-a2-lambda/3484426#3484426).

Comment: @NgChungTak Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!